# How to print the --comment for all non system Linux users?

Tags: shell-script, users

So far I found

```
awk -F'[/:]' '{if ($3 >= 1000 && $3 != 65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

To print all non system users. Next the username I want it show the user comment that was added with the -c option when I created the user.

How do I get the comment printed next to the usernames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 != 65534 { printf "%s -- %s\n",$1,$5;}' /etc/passwd
```

you can also use print

```
print $1 " -- " $5
```